# Avoid space from generated password code

Tags: php

If we run below code continuously, sometimes we found it generates some SPACE in the password which should not get.

Could anyone please tell how to avoid SPACE character from below generated password code:

**Here is the code:**

```
   function generateRandomPassword($length) {
      srand((double)microtime()*1000000);
      $password = "";
      $vowels = array("a", "e", "i", "o", "u");
      $cons = array("b", "c", "d", "g", "h", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "r",
"s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "tr", "cr", "br", "fr", "th", "dr", "ch", "ph", "wr", "
st", "sp", "sw", "pr", "sl", "cl");
      $num_vowels = count($vowels);
      $num_cons = count($cons);
      for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
         $c = $cons[rand(0, $num_cons - 1)];
         if (rand(0,1)) $c = strtoupper($c);
         $v = $vowels[rand(0, $num_vowels - 1)];
         if (rand(0,1)) $v = strtoupper($v);
         $password .= $c . $v;
         if (rand(0,4) == 0) $password .= rand(0,9);
      }
      return substr($password, 0, $length);
   }

$pwd = generateRandomPassword(12);

echo $pwd;
```

Comment: basic debugging: `if(($c == ' ') or ($v == ' ')) { die("got space at index $i");} ` or whatever. figure out where/when the space is coming from, and check the state of your system at that point.

Comment: I can not see how that would happen. just to make sure im not missing something obvious i ran it for 100,000 iterations. No spaces.

Comment: Though if the code above is an exact copy, in your `$cons` array, the element `"st"` has a line break in it, which would be undesirable, and possibly mistaken for a space char

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the return statement with the following:

```
  return trim(substr($password, 0, $length));
```

for all whitespace use:

```
return preg_replace('/\s+/', '', substr($password, 0, $length));
```

`trim()` Strip whitespace from the string. But the problem with your code is that there is a whitespace in the `st` of your `$cons` variable.

[PhP trim Function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)